# How do forwarding types apply to IoC?

Tags: inversion-of-control

I'm still learning Castle Windsor and I see that it supports forwarded types - a term I was unfamiliar with.

Quick Google search and I found [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404275.aspx) article that explains it pretty throughly however I still don't understand how this applies to IoC or how I would use them from a container and for what reason.

Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh man, just did a google search on 'Castle Windsor "Forwarded Types"' and got redirected right back to SO:

[Using Castle Windsor configuration files is it possible to delegate to another item declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344019/using-castle-windsor-configuration-files-is-it-possible-to-delegate-to-another)

and from there:

[What are “ForwardedTypes” in the context of Castle Windsor component registration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197274/what-are-forwardedtypes-in-the-context-of-castle-windsor-component-registration)

Maybe Jeff and the team should just give up on trying to have their own search and use google's.

Answer (score 0):

Type forwarding is a way to move type from one assembly to another without introducing breaking changes it has nothing to do with IoC. So you should not worry about this feature :)

Comment: Thats what I would think, but check out the castle windsor fluent interface, there's a Forward method