# Is there a way to set different lifecycle for each forwared type?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, castle-windsor, asp.net-core

Castle Windsor doesn't allow registrations that will contain a duplicate implementation type. It allows [type forwarding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197274/what-are-forwardedtypes-in-the-context-of-castle-windsor-component-registratio) which means that you can map the implementation type to more than one service types as long as you register it once.

ASP.NET vNext's [Dependency Injection](https://github.com/aspnet/DependencyInjection) library requires the same implementation type to be registered for multiple service types. However, these service types also have different lifecyles like shown [here](https://github.com/aspnet/DependencyInjection/blob/dev/test/Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection.Tests/Fakes/TestServices.cs#L14).

```
public static IEnumerable<IServiceDescriptor> DefaultServices()
{
    var describer = new ServiceDescriber();

    yield return describer.Transient<IFakeService, FakeService>();
    yield return describer.Scoped<IFakeScopedService, FakeService>();
    yield return describer.Singleton<IFakeSingletonService, FakeService>();
    yield return describer.Transient<IFakeFallbackService, FakeService>();
}
```

And here's the [Forward](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/f1290a6862b18e87fd610c04d5e482902b6f9fdc/src/Castle.Windsor/MicroKernel/Registration/ComponentRegistration.cs#L427) method signature:

```
public ComponentRegistration<TService> Forward(params Type[] types)
```

As you can see, it doesn't accept lifecycle parameters. Ninject test suite is passing. Can this be supported in Castle Windsor too?

Answer (score 0):

In Castle Windsor you can also simply register the same implementing type more than once. E.g.

```
container.Register(
    Component.For<IFakeService>().ImplementedBy<FakeService>(),
    Component.For<IReallyFakeService>().ImplementedBy<FakeService>());
```

I think that the whole concept of forwarding types ceases to make sense if you want different lifestyles, since the idea behind forwarding is that you get back the same instance of TypeA for each interface that you register for TypeA.

For example, with the above registrations I gave if I ran

```
var fakeService = container.Resolve<IFakeService>();
var reallyFakeService = container.Resolve<IReallyFakeService>();

Object.ReferenceEquals(fakeService, reallyFakeService);// => False
```

then I get back two different instances. However, if I instead use the registration

```
container.Register(
    Component
        .For<IFakeService>()
        .Forward<IReallyFakeService>()
        .ImplementedBy<FakeService>());
```

then my `Object.ReferenceEquals(fakeService, reallyFakeService);` will now return `true`. However, if you want different lifestyles for your interfaces this ceases to be true and you're back to where you were with multiple registrations anyway.